# Swift protocol with associatedtype error

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I create a function class : `Bar`, `Bar` use delegate that belong it to specific do something and this delegate comply with protocol `FooDelegate`, something like that:

```
protocol FooDelegate{
    associatedtype Item

    func invoke(_ item:Item)
}

class SomeFoo:FooDelegate{
    typealias Item = Int

    func invoke(_ item: Int) {
        //do something...
    }
}

class Bar{
    //In Bar instance runtime ,it will call delegate to do something...
    var delegate:FooDelegate!
}
```

but in class Bar : `var delegate:FooDelegate!` I got an error:

> Protocol 'FooDelegate' can only be used as a generic constraint
>   because it has Self or associated type requirements

How could I fix this?

Comment: you are getting this error because `FooDelegate` has an associated type `item`. Not sure what's your case, but you might want to do *type erasure*.

Comment: you are right ! I know that. But can you talk about type erasure for details,thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a couple of options.

Firstly you can use a specific type of `FooDelegate`, like `SomeFoo`:

```
class Bar {
    //In Bar instance runtime ,it will call delegate to do something...
    var delegate: SomeFoo!
}
```

Or you can make `Bar` generic and define what type of `Item` the delegate needs:

```
class Bar<F> where F: FooDelegate, F.Item == Int {
    //In Bar instance runtime ,it will call delegate to do something...
    var delegate: F!
}
```